# RewriteRule adding characters to redirected url

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I am trying to work on a set of RewriteRules but I am not getting the results I expect when the changes are pushed to the server. I hope I can safely assume that rewrites are possible since I do not get a server error when the .htaccess file is read.

An example of the problem I am having:

```
# (site)/about/faqs should link to about/about.php?p=faqs with this rule:  
RewriteRule ^about/faqs/?$ about/about.php?p=faqs [NC,L]
```

This works locally. However, when on the server using the same rules I get a Not Found error. "The requested url /h/s(site)/public/about/about.php" was not found on this server."

I think there is mapping happening on the host's side which results in the /public/ being added to the URL but I admittedly don't know much about this. My concern is both the /h/s and the public.

Also, there is  other rules on the server:

```
<Files (filename)> # deny access to a utility file
    Order allow, deny
    Deny from all
</Files>  
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/plain (and other rules for html, css, etc) #Compression
<files *.html>
    SetOutputFilter DEFLATE
</files>
Options -Indexes # disable directory access
```

I created these rules as a combination of reading examples and stack over for hints and tips. I've disabled the -Indexes as well and it caused no change.

Thank you in advance for any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your rule to:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(about)/(faqs)/?$ /$1/about.php?p=$2 [NC,L,QSA]
```

In your case rewrite rule is appending an extra `/about` to make URI `/h/s(site)/public/about/about.php`

Comment: Awesome. This worked for me on the server but not locally though. I run into a not found and the URL it is trying access locally is localhost:8888/(folder_name)/about/faqs and it gives me a "about/about/php was not found". Would I be able to add rules to work locally and on the server with the same file?

Comment: And...The RewriteCond is valid for all RewriteRules that follow it correct?

Comment: No `RewriteCond` is only applicable to immediate `RewriteRule` next to it.

Comment: What is the correct URL `localhost:8888/folder/about.php` OR `localhost:8888/folder/about/about.php`?

Comment: Thank you for your information about RewriteCond. I'll use that to work on the rest of the URLs. localhost:8888/folder/about/about.php is correct.